# Mixing hydrochloric acid and sulphuric acid, both concentrated

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, identification

In the chemistry lab, I stupidly decided to mix hydrochloric acid and sulphuric acid, both concentrated, in a random ratio, which was about $\pu{50 ml}$.

When I poured them in one test tube, the result was a vigorous reaction, with the green coloured liquid mixture "jumping" in the test tube and a white gas being released.

Could someone tell me what the resultant chemicals were?

Comment: Are you sure nothing else was in the test tube?

Comment: Did you add the sulfuric acid to the hydrochloric acid, or the reverse?  Hydrochloric acid stock solution is already about 63% water, so I would expect fewer side effects from adding sulfuric acid to hydrochloric.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-we-add-HCl-to-H2SO4 might help but I need to get more sources

Comment: Basically, if you pour $\ce{HCl}$ onto $\ce{H2SO4}$, hydrogen chloride gas will be emitted simply because $\ce{H2SO4}$ has a strong affinity for the water the hydrogen chloride is dissolved in.

Comment: @Molly The testube was clean.Well ,I added H2SO4 first and then added the HCl.The resultant liquid was slighly lighter than the HCl colour and loads of the white fumes was emmited,though the reactants were small in quantity.Even with the ventilator fans on,the gas pretty much covered the room.

Comment: Could someone tell the resultant solution's name ?

Answer (score 6):

Three things occurred. First, sulfuric acid as an high affinity for water (it is indeed used as a drying agent in some cases. For instance, if you wanted pure and anhydrous bromine, you could bubble wet bromine gas in concentrated sulfuric acid). So, one thing is the "stealing" of water by sulfuric acid, which took the solution one step forward the saturation point (with the release of gas).

The release of gas was aided by the exothermic reaction of sulfuric acid with water: (self) heating of the solution helped releasing the gas.

Edit: the following is an hypothesis, made by assuming that the "extreme" reaction conditions could have aided an unlikely redox reaction, but I am not sure about the oxidation of HCl:

*And finally, sulfuric acid is a oxidizing acid: it oxidized part of the hydrochloric acid to chlorine, which made the solution green (which probably was released as a gas, together with HCl).*

Comment: Does the release of Chlorine gas makes the solution green? I know the colour of it, is green.

Comment: Not the release of chlorine, but the presence of chlorine in solution!
When I was talking about the release of chlorine I was describing the composition of the gas, which probably contained part of the chlorine generated.
Oh, and it contained water vapor, probably (if the temperature was high enough, as I suspect)

Comment: The resultant was medium light green in colur,so the Clorine gas if formed,could'nt have dissolved in the solution.

Comment: What colour do you see when you put a droplet of red wine in a large glass of water?

Comment: But what you are talking about is diffusion,which strays us from my next sub-question:Did the acids mix to form an Aqua Regia type of solution , and if theexperiment was done in a closed environment ,could it have killed me ?

Comment: Yes, the acid did mix. It was not acqua regia, but yet it's a cute mix of acids.
And yes, in a closed enviroment breathing hydrochloric acid and chlorine gas is not too good for your body.
In fact, chlorine was used as an irritating (and toxic) war gas.
And acid... well, it's acid.
But don't worry: luckily nowadays we have aspiration apparatus, and a short exposure, like in your case, is not a terrible thing.
You just learned a lesson, I guess, which is what the laboratory is for.

Comment: Yeah,but I want to know the chemical and commercial name for the acid and the gas,as I could not have been the only guy ever to do so.

Comment: Are you sure sulfuric acid is oxidizing enough to oxidize chloride ions? I can't find the redox potential, but I do know that in the lab we prepare gaseous hydrogen chloride by dripping concentrated sulfuric acid into sodium chloride, and I've never seen any oxidation of our reagents from any chlorine gas that might form.

Comment: I confess that I am puzzled and that I was puzzled, but I saw no other explanation.
What puzzles me is that every redox chart says it doesn't happen.
But if you look at Pourbaix diagrams of chlorine and sulfur, you see that at pH=0 Cl2 has Eh of around 1.4 (decreasing with acidity), and hydrogen sulphate of around 1.25 (increasing with acidity). Now, there are two problems: 1.the pH is probably "negative". 2.Is our sistem aqueous, with such an amount of concentrated acid? If it's not, how does it behave?
My answer derived from the only explanation I could find for the green.

Comment: Also, your method is indeed used, and it works (it's a typical reaction employed in a Kipp generator). But I wonder if the extreme reaction conditions (high temperature, high concentration of acids in the contact area) could be an answer.

Comment: Could oxygen be involved? It's reduction potential turns more positive at lower pH too. And HCl bottles turn yellow over time too.

Answer (score 4):

Sulfuric acid occupies several categories besides corrosive, one of which is as a dehydrant. The water removed from hydrochloric acid produce a vapour of hydrogen chloride. The solution is effervescent. There should not be a green colour unless the test tube was contaminated. I was hoping that you had done this in a fume hood.

I did this using 10 ml of each acid knowing what to expect. The fumes actually escaped as I shut the sash quickly causing turbulence. The fumes were quickly detected. If this were done in a prep room without a fume hood, with larger quantities you would be lucky to walk away from this! Despite their being stored together, they are not compatible.